# NextJS 13 build error: PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page: /

Tags: next.js, build, next.js13

When trying to build NextJS 13 app, I get an error  `Cannot find module for page:` which seems to randomly alternate between all pages.

Steps tried:

- adding exportPathMap results in `Error occurred prerendering page`
- switch from `getStaticProps` to `fetch()` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704204/next-js-error-pagenotfounderror-cannot-find-module-for-page-404)
- removing `node_modules` and `.next` folders
- running `npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004513/nextjs-export-gives-cannot-find-module-for-page)

Using the app directory.

Open to any suggestions to be able to deploy my app.

EDIT:

changing `"build": "next build && next export",`
to `"build": "next build"` in `package.json` works for building. As per [official documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap) Next JS 13 **export is still work in progress**

Is there any viable option to deploy Next JS 13 app to Firebase or Vercel?